# What is the error "msgfmt: cannot locate ITS rules for data/org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.policy.in" while building yocto wpa repo

Tags: yocto, gettext, yocto-recipe, msgfmt

I am trying to build the meta layer https://github.com/LairdCP/meta-laird-cp
I am using the layer meta-summit-radio-pre-3.4/ for my build. Most of the components build with the exception of 'summit-networkmanager-lwb'. This component creates the error:

```
summit-networkmanager-lwb/11.39.0.18-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/msgfmt: cannot locate ITS rules for data/org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.policy.in
make[2]: *** [Makefile:21455: data/org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.policy] Error 1
```

I tried installing `libappstream-glib-dev`. It didn't work.

Whats going on here? How do I debug this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Ubuntu 18.04 or later as the host

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 22.04 or docker with 20.04.

Comment: Take the latest version of meta-summit-radio, I patched the problem, the problem was that upstream later Network Manager cannot be built on a configuration without polkit when using autoconf/automake build.

Comment: I updated the meta layer to use 11.39.0.18-r0 and I got a different error :
 /usr/src/debug/summit-networkmanager-lwb/11.39.0.18-r0/build/../lrd-network-manager-11.39.0.18/src/nmcli/common.c:933: undefined reference to `rl_echo_signal_char'